# How to remove All strong tags from HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to remove all strong tags from HTML page?

Comment: $('strong').remove();

Comment: Do you mean remove including content or replace with normal text?

Comment: Can you clarify on intent? Do you want the end result of `<strong>Strong Bad!</strong>` to be nothing or `Strong Bad!`?

Comment: A different approach would be to use CSS to prevent content in strong tags from being displayed differently.

Comment: @user2182349 How can we do that ?

Comment: In a CSS file -
    strong { font-weight: normal; }

Answer (score 3):

As already pointed out, using CSS is the correct solution and also way simpler.

Yet, if one *really* wanted to remove all strong tags (along with content) this code snippet would do it (tested in IE,FF,Chrome):

```
function removeStrongContent() {
    var i, nodes = document.getElementsByTagName( 'strong' );
    for(i=nodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if ( nodes[i] ) nodes[i].parentElement.removeChild( nodes[i] );
    }
}
```